# standard function from an input box and show results

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want get the standard functions from an inputbox and show results in a message box.

**Examples:**

```
Input textbox= "month(now()) - 1"

message box = 8



Input textbox= "year(now())"

message box = 2019
```

Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though the messagebox will show the correct result as of this date:

```
MsgBox Eval("month(now()) - 1")
MsgBox Eval("year(now())")
```